# How to bind method on RadioGroup on checkChanged event with data-binding

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-radiogroup

I was searching over the internet for how to perform the new cool android data-binding over the `RadioGroup` and I didn't find a single blog post about it.

Its a simple scenario, based on the radio button selected, I want to attach a callback event using android data binding. I don't find any method on the xml part which allows me to define a callback.

Like here is my RadioGroup:

```
      <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/split_type_radio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/split_type_equal"
            android:gravity="center"
            <!-- which tag ? -->
            android:orientation="horizontal">

           ...

       </RadioGroup>
```

How do I attach a handler method which will be called on `RadioGroup`'s `checkChnged` event will fire using data-binding?

I have tried using `onClick` (don't know if it is the same) in layout file and defining method in the Activity and located it using this in the layout file:

```
   <variable
        name="handler"
        type="com.example.MainActivity"/>

  ...
   <RadioGroup
        android:onClick="handler.onCustomCheckChanged"
        .. >
```

And defined method `onCustomCheckChanged` like this:

```
public void onCustomCheckChanged(RadioGroup radio, int id) {
     // ...
}
```

But, it gives me the compilation error:

> Error:(58, 36) Listener class android.view.View.OnClickListener with method onClick did not match signature of any method handler.onCustomCheckChanged

I have seen many blogs mentioning it is possible with `RadioGroup` but non of them really say how. How can I handle this with `data-binding` ?

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38145783/cusom-event-attributes-in-android-bindings-apponmyevent/38197468#38197468)? I think you can do something similiar. If you still need help. I'll look into it on monday :)

Comment: @Amylinn Thanks for the link. I really appreciate it :) I can try but for what attribute I should do it in xml? Like for checkChanged event in radio button there isn't any attribute which let's me provide a method. While 'onClick'  may not work if I pragmatically change the radio button (for example, reset button switch to the default values).

Comment: I think the corresponding attribute would be `app:onCheckedChangeListener`.

Comment: @Amylinn Got it! Posted an answer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

After digging to the bunch of methods, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798426/how-to-databind-to-ontextchanged-for-an-edittext-on-android) question on SO which helped me understand how to bind single methods of listeners.

Here is what to do with RadioGroup:

In `RadioGroup` listener you have a method `onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup g, int id)`. So you can directly bound that method to your handler or your activity by passing an instance of it as a variable in layout file and calling a method with the same signature.

So call on layout file like this:

```
  <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/split_type_radio"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:checkedButton="@+id/split_type_equal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onCheckedChanged="@{handler.onSplitTypeChanged}"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

       ...

   </RadioGroup>
```

And in my activity or handler, I need to simply provide the method with same name and signature like this:

```
public void onSplitTypeChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup,int id) {
  // ...
}
```

Just make sure method is public.

**NOTE:** This works for any (most of, I have not tried all) listener methods. Like for `EditText` you can provide `android:onTextChanged` and so on.

Comment: When i try using the android:onCheckedChanged in my xml it says unknown attribute , i have managed to get data binding to work with on click listener but this same solution isnt working for me

Comment: @JudeFernandes They have some errors in the lint at present in the android studio, but they compiles fine and works. Just ignore the warning. Can you explain a bit more about your issue?

Comment: how to handle two way handle through this approach ?

Comment: what if i want name of that checked radio button. ?

Comment: @RayVaniya You have the radio group instance. Get it from that radio group

Comment: 1) it works only View to data and not the other way around. 2) it means adding dependency on View ids - which defeats the purpose of using databinding.

Answer (score 22):

I am using a string, and in this case I have bindable based on `viewModel.getCommuteType() viewModel.setCommuteType(String)`

```
<RadioGroup
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RadioButton
    android:checked="@{viewModel.commuteType.equals(Commute.DRIVING)}"
    android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.setCommuteType(Commute.DRIVING)}"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="D"/>

<RadioButton
    android:checked="@{viewModel.commuteType.equals(Commute.BICYCLE)}"
    android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.setCommuteType(Commute.BICYCLE)}"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="B"/>

<RadioButton
    android:checked="@{viewModel.commuteType.equals(Commute.WALKING)}"
    android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.setCommuteType(Commute.WALKING)}"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="W"/>

<RadioButton
    android:checked="@{viewModel.commuteType.equals(Commute.BUS)}"
    android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.setCommuteType(Commute.BUS)}"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="T"/>
```

Comment: how to validate it ? is it checked or not

Comment: checkout LiveData.Transformations to benefit from watching another LiveData such as the case of my `viewMdodel.commuteType`, in this way you can define a `LiveData<Boolean>`  watching over `viewModel.commuteType` initially having `Commute.NONE` which produces false, and if it has any other value then it's true.  https://proandroiddev.com/clean-easy-new-how-to-architect-your-app-part-4-livedata-transformations-f0fd9f313ec6

Comment: any time brother. hope that helped you out.

Comment: used this solution with `MediatorLiveData` it worked flawlessly.

Comment: @sud007very nice to hear!

Comment: Where do you set `Commute.DRIVING`?

Comment: It's been a while, and I am doing Flutter, but I believe Commute.xxxx were enums based on strings. Good luck!!

Answer (score 22):

After some hours I found easy way: two-way databinding in android. It's base skeleton with [livedata](/questions/tagged/livedata) and Kotlin. Also you can use ObservableField()

1. Set your [viewmodel](/questions/tagged/viewmodel) to data
2. Create your [radiogroup](/questions/tagged/radiogroup) with buttons as you like. Important: set all radio buttons id !!!
3. Set in your radio group two-way [binding](/questions/tagged/binding) to checked variable (use viewmodel variable)
4. Enjoy)

---

layout.xml

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="VM"
        type="...YourViewModel" />
</data>


<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/settings_block_env"
            ...
            >


            <RadioGroup

                android:id="@+id/env_radioGroup"
                android:checkedButton="@={VM.radio_checked}">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/your_id1"/>

                <RadioButton
                   android:id="@+id/your_id2" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/your_id3"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/your_id4"/>
            </RadioGroup>

        </LinearLayout>
```

---

```
class YourViewModel(): ViewModel {

var radio_checked = MutableLiveData<Int>()


init{
    radio_checked.postValue(R.id.your_id1)//def value
}

//other code
}
```

Comment: This is simplest solution with two way data binding. And you can use default value as constructor param `MutableLiveData(R.id.your_id1)`

Comment: Of course , it is. Also instead of var should use val.

Comment: what shall I do with `radio_checked.postValue(R.id.your_id1)` if they are multiple I want to validate them for example if I have two radio button male and female want to make validation on check@StanislavBondar

Comment: @ELTEGANIMOHAMED I'm not sure, but you should set observers for all LiveData and invoke  yourValidate() method. Or create another isValid: LiveData<Boolean>.

Comment: @SeregaMaleev  `radio_checked.postValue(R.id.your_id1)//def value`
how would you detect which RadioButton has been clicked ? and how can we get back the value of the radio button that was selected by the user ?

Comment: android:checkedButton

Comment: @Cosmic Dev  You need to set the observer in your fragment or activity.

Comment: This is by far the best and most true to data binding solution for this question. Thank you.

Comment: While this works, it means adding dependency on View ids - which defeats the purpose of using databinding.

Comment: So far this is the cleanest and easiest way!

Comment: And this only works in Kotlin

Answer (score 7):

Often you care more about **what** was actually checked instead of "something was checked". In such case alternative solution is to ignore RadioGroup and bind all items as below:

```
<RadioGroup (...) >
        <RadioButton (...)
            android:checked="@={viewModel.optionA}"/>

        <RadioButton (...)
            android:checked="@={viewModel.optionB}"/>

        <RadioButton (...)
            android:checked="@={viewModel.optionC}"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

where optionA, optionB and optionC are defined in ViewModel like below:

```
public final ObservableBoolean optionA = new ObservableBoolean();
public final ObservableBoolean optionB = new ObservableBoolean();
public final ObservableBoolean optionC = new ObservableBoolean();
```

This is usually enough, however if you want to react immediately on click then you can add callBacks and use them like that:

```
OnPropertyChangedCallback userChoosedA = new OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPropertyChanged(Observable sender, int propertyId) {
        (...) // basically propertyId can be ignored in such case
    }
};

optionA.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(userChoosedA);
```

Advantage of such approach is that you don't need to compare and track "id".

Comment: Where does that piece of code go?

Comment: @TheRealChx101 it really depends but in the simplest possible case "RadioGroup" part goes to xml and two other snippets goes to activity.

Answer (score 5):

In my current project, I did it like this. 
I have three currency in the project and I choose one of them via RadioGroup.

It's enum with currencies:

```
enum class Currency(val value: Byte) {
    USD(0),
    EUR(1),
    RUB(2);

    companion object Create {
        fun from(sourceValue: Byte): Currency = values().first { it.value == sourceValue }
        fun from(sourceValue: String): Currency = values().first { it.toString() == sourceValue }
    }
}
```

A piece of my ViewModel:

```
    class BaseCurrencyViewModel : ViewModelBase<BaseCurrencyModelInterface>() {
        /**
         * Selected currency
         */
        val currency: MutableLiveData<Currency> = MutableLiveData()

        /**
         *
         */
        init {
            currency.value = Currency.USD   // Init value
        }
  }
```

Part of my layout (pay attention to binding in RadioGroup and tags of RadioButton):

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/currencySwitchers"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    app:selectedCurrency = "@{viewModel.currency}"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/usdSwitcher"

        android:text="USD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:tag="USD"
    />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/eurSwitcher"

        android:text="EUR"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:tag="EUR"
    />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rubSwitcher"

        android:text="RUB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:tag="RUB"
    />
</RadioGroup>
```

And the final part - binding adapter.

```
@BindingAdapter("selectedCurrency")
fun setSelectedCurrency(view: View, value: MutableLiveData<Currency>?) {
    view.getParentActivity()?.let { parentActivity ->
        value?.observe(parentActivity, Observer { value ->
            view.findViewWithTag<RadioButton>(value.toString())
                ?.also {
                    if(!it.isChecked) {
                        it.isChecked = true
                    }
                }
            }
        )

        (view as RadioGroup).setOnCheckedChangeListener { radioGroup, checkedId ->
            val currency = Currency.from(radioGroup.findViewById<RadioButton>(checkedId).tag as String)
            if(value != null && value.value != currency) {
                value.value = currency
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this way, I got two-way binding between RadioGroup and a property in my ViewModel.

Comment: do you have your code in android - java and not Kotlin?

Comment: @batsheva No, sorry. I don't use Java recently.

Comment: @AlexShevelev Thank you...for the solution