# How to use Two way data binding with radio button in android

Tags: android, android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding

I am trying to use two way data binding with the radio button. It is working fine with one way like below,

`android:checked="@{registration.gender.equals(Gender.FEMALE.getValue())}"`.

But My problem is that, I need to set the value of selected radio button in my model.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
   <data>
      <import type="com.callhealth.customer.comman.enums.Gender" />
      <import type="android.text.TextUtils" />
      <import type="java.lang.Integer" />
      <variable name="callback" type="com.callhealth.customer.usermanagement.callback.RegistrationCallback" />
      <variable name="registration" type="com.callhealth.customer.usermanagement.model.request.LoginAndRegistrationRequestModel" />
   </data>
   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:orientation="vertical">
      <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="@string/label_gender" android:textSize="15sp" />
      <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/gender_group" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:orientation="horizontal">
         <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:checked="@={registration.gender.equals(Gender.MALE.getValue())}" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/label_male" />
         <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:layout_marginStart="20dp" android:checked="@={registration.gender.equals(Gender.FEMALE.getValue())}" android:text="@string/label_female" />
      </RadioGroup>
   </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

My Model Class

```
public class LoginAndRegistrationRequestModel extends BaseObservable {

    private Integer gender;

    @Bindable
    public Integer getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(Integer gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.gender);
    }   
}
```

When i am trying to use

```
android:checked="@={registration.gender.equals(Gender.FEMALE.getValue())}"
```

Gradel is throwing an error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
  ****/ data binding error ****msg:The expression registrationGender.equals(com.callhealth.customer.comman.enums.Gender.MALE.getValue()) cannot be inverted: There is no inverse for method equals, you must add an @InverseMethod annotation to the method to indicate which method should be used when using it in two-way binding expressions
  file:S:\Umesh\android\android_studio_workspace\CallHealth\app\src\main\res\layout\content_user_registration.xml
  loc:148:48 - 148:97
  ****\ data binding error ****
```

Answer (score 6):

[Try it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54261803/8007142)

After some hours I found an easy way: two-way databinding in android. Its a base skeleton with livedata and Kotlin. Also, you can use ObservableField()

- Set your viewmodel to data
- Create your radiogroup with buttons as you like. Important: set all
  radio buttons id !!!
- Set in your radio group two-way binding to checked variable (use
  viewmodel variable)
- Enjoy)

layout.xml

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="VM"
        type="...YourViewModel" />
</data>


<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/settings_block_env"
            ...
            >


            <RadioGroup

                android:id="@+id/env_radioGroup"
                android:checkedButton="@={VM.radio_checked}">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/your_id1"/>

                <RadioButton
                   android:id="@+id/your_id2" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/your_id3"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/your_id4"/>
            </RadioGroup>

        </LinearLayout>
```

```
class YourViewModel(): ViewModel {
    
    var radio_checked = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    
    
    init{
        radio_checked.postValue(R.id.your_id1)//def value
    }
    
    //other code
    }
```

Comment: So the `radio_checked` stores the `id`? What if I want the index (position)?

Answer (score 0):

You are binding it to a `boolean` EXPRESSION.  It has no idea what method to call when setting it. I would try making your property a `boolean` (e.g. `isFemale`).  It sounds like there is also a way to indicate the setter with the @InverseMethod annotation, but I haven't used that and it seems to me that the `boolean` approach would be more straightforward. You could always implement the `boolean` properties in terms of the `Integer` `gender` field if you wanted to refer to the `Integer` elsewhere in java code.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a `@InverseMethod` for the custom converter (the error says it can't convert equals to gender basically) or just use a boolean observable for the changes and the setter will work out of the box.

for example if you have

```
val isFemale = ObservableBoolean()
```

in your ViewModel this will work out of the box

```
android:checked="@={viewModel.isFemale}"
```

of course you need to provide ViewModel variable into the layout binding.

To "fix" what you have there you need to create your own inverse method and setter for checked.

```
@InverseMethod("toGender")
public static int isFemaleGender(Integer gender) {
        return gender.equals(Gender.FEMALE.getValue());
    } 

public static Integer toGender(boolean checked) {
        if (checked) 
           return Gender.FEMALE;
        else 
           return Gender.MALE;
    }
```

Both of these approaches will only work if you have 2 options as you do true false basically. It is either you create an `Observable` for each option or go with the solution provided by @Serega Maleev